# Using AJAX to trigger a PHP report and not waiting for completion

Tags: php, ajax

I've got a page that triggers a php report by an AJAX request and the report is saved as a file on the server for later downloading. So the actual AJAX request doesn't need to return anything meaningful.

This all works fine. However, my problem is that the report can take quite a while to generate and as the user doesn't need to wait I'd like to free them up to do whatever.

I was intending to try and use:

```
fastcgi_finish_request()
```

to clear the request but the site has an old version of php 5.2.11 so I can't use this. Is there another way I could return something to the browser so the request can be completed but continue afterwards generating the report?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    cache:false,
    timeout:1, //use this 
    type:"POST",
    url:"report.php",
    data:allFormValues,
    success:function(response){  }
   });
```

use timeout if you dont want to wait longer

Comment: I can get the timeout event to fire - but if I try and reload the page at this point I still get a delay while the report finishes generation.

Comment: it's a ajax why you are reloading the page it is done without loading the page

Comment: Yes that's true normally but the page displays various data. I effect what I'm doing is allowing the user to refresh the data that is displayed on screen before the report that is saved to disc has been finished. It works fine if I look at a page on another site - I can view that page and the report is save to file some minutes later. Its just if I'm trying to refresh the same page it waits until the report has been produced before the page is re displayed.